# group records bases on one column name in data set and display all the values corresponding to the column for which records are grouped in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

For example, if I have a data-set as below

```
ID ITEM
1   A
2   B
3   C
1   B
1   C
2   A
```

then need a sql query which gives output as below:

```
ID  ITEM
1    A, B, C
2    B, A
3    C
```

That is how to group based on ID and display all the values pertaining to another column attributes in SQL.

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using.

Comment: This is known as a [tag:pivot] operation, and has established solutions for all systems

Comment: I am using MS sql server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Replace the table names with your table name and use the below query:

```
Select src.ID,
       src.Items [Items]
    From
        (
            Select distinct T2.ID, 
                (
                    STUFF((Select T1.Item + ',' AS [text()]
                    From [Yourtable-Name] T1
                    Where T1.ID = T2.ID
                    ORDER BY T1.ID
                    For XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
                ) [Items]
            From [YourTableName] T2
        ) [src]
```

Comment: Hi Jibin,Thanks for your response.

Comment: @user1829708 You can mark it as useful if it worked for you

Comment: This was useful but take time. i am looking for optimized query.